# How to set the Figure title, not the ax title when using pandas plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

After using pandas `df.plot`, I want to set the title of the whole figure, not the title inside the figure, how to achieve this?

The following two codes explain my question better:

I want to add title here:

```
lst = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
plt.figure("I want the title here!")
plt.plot([0, 1, 2], lst)
plt.show()
```

How to achieve this when using `df.plot`?

```
lst = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
ax = df.plot()
ax.set_title("not the title here")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an `axis` object from `df.plot(**kwargs)`, and use `get_figure()` to get the figure object, then set the figure title.

```py
ax = df.plot()
ax.get_figure().canvas.set_window_title('Is this the title you want?')
```

Comment: Not what I want, please run my sample and see the effect.

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse Ah now I know it and edit the answer. Now it should work.

Comment: Yes, that is the title I want.